Is there a way that playwright can run the teardown of a playwright project even if test gets interrupted by using cmd + c
 projects: [
    {
      name: 'citizen-users-teardown',
      testMatch: '**playwright/tests/bootstrap/users/citizen-users.teardown.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'citizen-users-setup',
      testMatch: '**playwright/tests/bootstrap/users/citizen-users.setup.ts',
      teardown: 'citizen-users-teardown',
    },
    {
      name: 'citizen-auth-setup',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      testMatch: '**playwright/tests/bootstrap/auth/citizen-auth.setup.ts',
      dependencies: ['citizen-users-setup'],
      teardown: 'citizen-auth-teardown',
    },
    {
      name: 'citizen-auth-teardown',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      testMatch: '**playwright/tests/bootstrap/auth/citizen-auth.teardown.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'full-functional',
      use: {...devices['Desktop Chrome']  },
      dependencies: ['citizen-auth-setup'],
    },
  ],

I have this setup above for my playwright project. I am finding that when I press cmd + c in mac the teardown projects do not run, is there a way (without using playwrights global teardown) to ensure the teardown always runs even if tests are interrupted?
I ask this because during the teardown process I am using playwrights request: APIRequestContext object and my own custom playwright fixtures, which I cannot access using the global teardown or setup method.
I have tried asking ChatGPT which did not give me a good solution.

Try sending it a SIGTERM. If it implements graceful termination for it, there's probably an easy way to enable it for SIGINT (control-C) as well.
